# Error in executing a command when starting a container using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to start my container and once it's running, start a service in the container. I'm using a docker-compose file and start my service in the ''command'' section of it as follows

```
services:
  service1:
    image: image_name:tag
    container_name: cname
    command:
         - exec start_service $VAR1 $VAR2
    ports:
        - "5458:5000"
    env_file: ./variables.txt
```

values of `VAR1` and `VAR2` are coming from the variables.txt file which is specified in the `env_file` section. Also `start_service` exist in the $PATH of the container. When I start the docker-compose, it first shows some warning that the `VAR1` and `VAR2` are not set and also errors out with the following error message.

```
 Cannot start service service1: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "exec: \"exec start_service   \": executable file not found in $PATH".
```

So it looks like the command is executed before the env variables are set and also it says start_service is not in $PATH which is not true.

What's going wrong here?

p.s. I did some test and commented the command in the docker-compose, when the container started I went to the container and ensured that `start_service` exist in the $PATH.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to put `exec` before `start_service`. Docker will do that for you, so if you take a closer look at the error message you'll notice that `exec: \"exec start_service   \"`

Comment: I removed it but I'm still getting the same error, besides, the env are not set when that command is getting executed, that's the other issue